# php image slice with apply white bg for image

Tags: php, image

I need to slice the image in horizontal manner. For this I used the below code

```
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$fileData = getimagesize($filename);

$source_handle = ImageCreateFromJPEG($filename);

$imageW = $fileData[0];
$imageH = $fileData[1];

/* Cropping Parameters */
$part1X = 0;
$part1Y = 0;
$part1W = $imageW;
$part1H = $imageH/2;

$part2X = 0;
$part2Y = $imageH/2;
$part2W = $imageW;
//$part2H = $imageH/2;
$part2H = $imageH;


$to_crop_array = array('x' =>$part1X , 'y' =>$part1Y, 'width' => $part1W, 'height'=> $part1H);
$imgCroped1 = imagecrop($source_handle, $to_crop_array);

$to_crop_array = array('x' =>$part2X , 'y' =>$part2Y, 'width' => $part2W, 'height'=> $part2H);
$imgCroped2 = imagecrop($source_handle, $to_crop_array);

/* Image Split */
imagejpeg($imgCroped1, '1a.jpg', 100);
imagejpeg($imgCroped2, '1b.jpg', 100);
```

By this code the image sliced into 2 parts. But some images saved with black bg. I need to change this black bg to white in color.

For this I used the below code.

```
// set background to white
$white = imagecolorallocate($imgCroped2, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($imgCroped2, 0, 0, $white);    
imagejpeg($imgCroped2, 'xx.jpg', 100);
```

But the white bg is not applied. How to change this code to apply white bg for the sliced image. Please help me.